# Date and time format shows incorrectly on iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have some trouble with the date format on iOS. On Android it displays correctly.

```
var d = local.ToLongDateString();
var t = local.ToShortTimeString();
return string.Format("{0} kl. {1}", d, t);
```

This will display the date in English, and the time with 12-hour format. The phone region is set to Norway, phone language is Norwegian while English is given as the secondary language.

Result on iOS:

> Sunday, April 8, 2018 kl. 6.00 PM

Result on Android:

> søndag 8. april, 2018 kl. 18:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer within the [Xamarin Docs - iOS Localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/localization/):

> If `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` has not been specified in the Info.plist file, the Xamarin.iOS build tools currently use a default value of `en_US.`

The solution was to edit Info.plist with a text editor and add the following key:

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>no</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could provide a format yourself:

```
local.ToString("dddd, MMMM d, yyyy kl. hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

The code above should return a consistent result on all the targeting platforms:
 `Wednesday, April 4, 2018 kl. 10:24 AM`

You can easily play with the solution here: http://rextester.com/PPP50237

More information on Custom Date and Time Format Strings can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).